# Secure joining process using Local Google & Apple HomeKit SDK's

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home, homekit, ios-homekit

I am working on smart home devices based on the zigbee, z-wave & wifi.
I would like to make my smart home devices compatible with the google local SDK & apple home kit.
For that,
I would like to know how the provisioning is managed by the SDK or APP to add a device securely into the network.

1. Are there any standards mentioned by Google Or Apple?
2. How the security is managed by them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to Google's smart home platform, the [seamless setup using Bluetooth](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/seamless-setup) is documented along with the rest of the developer documentation. That should answer your questions for that platform. I don't know about how Apple does it in their HomeKit platform.